# Xamarin.iOS - 64 bit upgrade

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am upgrading an old 32bit Xamarin iOS app to a 64bit version.  I believe all that needs to be changed is the settings in this window.  Are these setting correct for rebuilding the app to a 64 bit version?

[image]

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/macios/unified/updating-ios-apps/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We currently have an app in the apple appstore that supports 64 bit, so heres a photo of our current build configuration for ad-hoc (which is what we use to submit manually via application uploader). Your settings above should be fine.

Personally I don't like to use the experimental garbage collector for release builds, but totally upto you.

[image]